# The <base href="./"> was not working in index.html

Tags: web

Whenever I am using `<base href="./">` in my **index.html** file it was showing the following error

```
Error: The base href in "web/index.html" must be absolute (i.e. start with a "/"), but found: `<base href="./">`.
```

after rectifying the error and using `<base href="/">` the content was not rendering on the screen later I also remove the `<base>` tag but it doesn't work.
How to specify the current directory in `<base>` tag without proving the full relative path?

Comment: Are you using a server where / maps to index.html, or are you trying to point your browser at a directory?

Answer (score 0):

Add `<base href="/">` this line instead of  `<base href="$FLUTTER_BASE_HREF">` this solved the problem for me

if not run the **flutter clean** command and try to run